# How to referesh one view UI from other view UI

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, prism-4

I have two Views called UserView and RoleView.

UserView.xaml contains RadGridView which contain three columns
**UserID** (Label) | **UserName** (Label)| **Role** (Dropdown).

RoleView.xaml contains one TextBox where i can add Roles into database.
**Role** (Textbox).

- Step 1. Now first i open the UserView.xaml and it will display
  records from database with appropriate roles.
- Step 2. Now i open new page RoleView.xaml (minimize UserView.xaml).
- Step 3. I have added one role. (AdminRole)
- Step 4. Now i open UserView.xaml (it is already in memory, so just i
  navigate to this page)
- Step 5. Now i double click to any of the row with Role (Dropdown
  column) it will comes into edit mode and populate list of roles.

  ```
  **but it will not display recently added role (AdminRole) in dropdown. because of the data source will not getting referesh.**
  ```

*If i am closing the UserView.xaml and reopen this page then it will display recently added role (AdminRole) in dropdown.*

**Note:** my requirement is like, i have to update or notify all opened views once any of the change from anywhere.

I am using 
Silverlight 4 (MVVM)
PRISM
telerik RadGridView

Your help/comment/suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 1):

Prism comes with an Event Aggreator. Where you have publishers and subscribers to these events, which we'll call "messages". Have a look at the MDSN link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx

What this means is you can have each view subscribe to an update message and have them update whenever they receive this message. So you could send an "update" message each time a view changes.